# Convert String elements to Array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a String :

```
str="[a],[b],[c]";
```

How can I convert str to array in Java (Android):

```
array[0] -> a
array[1] -> b
array[2] -> c
```

**EDIT:**
and what about multidimensinal array? str="[["a1","a2","a3"],["b1","b2","b3"]]";

Comment: use `regex` to spilt the string, and then populate the array

Comment: I agree with Sajan...this way is more performant.

Comment: i thought there is a function for it..

Answer (score 5):

try

```
String str="[a],[b],[c]";
str= str.replaceAll("\\]|\\[", "");
String[] arr= str.split(",");
```

===========================================

**update**

converting multi dimension array to single dimension is already answered in SO please check [change multidimensional array to single array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881816/change-multidimensional-array-to-single-array)

just copied the solution

```
 public static String[] flatten(String[][] data) {
        List<String> toReturn = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String[] sublist : Arrays.asList(data)) {
            for (String elem : sublist) {
                toReturn.add(elem);
            }
        }
        return toReturn.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
```

Comment: ok thanks.. it works.. and what about multidimensinal array? str="[["a1","a2","a3"],["b1","b2","b3"]]";

Comment: @ratsbaf if it works then accept upog's answer - for multidimensional arrays try applying what you just learned and, if you have another problem, come back and ask another question - but remember to demonstrate some effort or you'll get downvoted again

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method

Answer (score 1):

You can use following way.

```
String Vstr = "[a],[b],[c]";
String[] array = Vstr.replaceAll("\\]|\\[", "").split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to process your string and build your array. You could either take a look at [`.split(String regex)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) (which might require you to do some more processing to clean the string) or else, use a regular expression and do as follows:

- Use a regex like so: `\[([^]]+?)\]`. This will seek out characters in between square brackets and put them into a group.
- Use the [`.find()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method available from the [`Matcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class and iterate over the matches. Put everything into a list so that you can put in as many hits as you need.
- If you really need the result to be in an array, use the [`.toArray()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the regex and what npinti, i think, is talking about:

```
    String myStrg = "[a],[b],[c]";
    int numCommas = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < myStrg.length(); i++ )
    {
        // Count commas
        if( myStrg.charAt(i) == ',' )
        {
            numCommas++;
        }
    }
    // Initialize array
    myArry = new String[numCommas];
    myArry = myStrg.split(",");

    // Loop through and print contents of array
    for( String arryStrg: myArry )
    {
        System.out.println( arryStrg );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
String str="[a],[b],[c]";
str= str.replaceAll("\\]|\\[", "");
String[] arr= str.split(",");
```